# transform a list of lists in the form of a tree structure for efficient searching

Tags: list, search, tree

As part of the requirement regarding a project i need to search for a node (string) in a list of lists.The set consists of N lists , each of which is a list consisting of L nodes. here N is of large value, typically >= 5000 and L is =< 100.

1. What data structure will be ideal to transform the L nodes of each list so that search will be quicker and easier ?

   I am not sure about converting the list in the form of some kind of tree structure as the nodes of the list are strings ( can i manually assign some no. to each of the node and convert it into a suitable tree structure so that search will be quicker ? if yes which tree structure will be ideal)

Thanks in advance for any help regarding this.

Comment: Are you sure a simple linear search will be to slow?

Comment: Can you give a bit more specifics?
- Should the string retain order?
- Is it alright to flatten the list, or are the sublists important?
- What's the structure mostly used for?

Comment: @Noctua : Thanks for the help, regarding the details asked, the strings mentioned in the sub lists need to retain order, they are city names traversed in the sequence specified in the list.

Comment: @SWeko: the reason i think liner search will be slow is since each sub list will contain a set of strings, if i need to search for a string in a list of list it may take some time. Importantly I need to do this search large no. of times,typically ~ 1000

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two structures:

1) Order the lists of string so that you can do a binary search ( complexity: O(n*log(n)) for insertion and search )

2) Better: put the strings in a hashmap, so that insertion and search is O(1).

You can also use a B-tree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), but it is similar to keeping the lists ordered, and I think it would cause more overhead.

Definitely I would go for (2) if performance is an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the sublist consisting of a set of strings is already maintained based on a particular order, like sequence in which a set of cities are traversed. regarding  maintaining a Hashmap for such a large set of strings would'nt they be a overhead?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your data structure, but if you have ordered lists, why not using binary search? You even have it for free in a method in Collections class.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a hashing map or sorted tree, mapping the Strings (city names) to a tuple of the form (index_in_main_list, index_in_sublist).

In case of the hashing map, this allows constant time lookup of the String, while still allowing iteration over the original list.

You mentioned the Strings where cities, and the sublists were traveling routes. As cities will probably lay on several traveling routes, you should keep several tuples for each hash.

In Java, for instance, the type declarations would be:

```
public class IndexTuple {
    public final int fst;
    public final int snc;
    public IndexTuple(int fst, int snd) {
        this.fst = fst;
        this.snd = snd;
    }
}

HashMap<String, ArrayList<IndexTuple>> lookupMap;

// The sublists of cities. I've used an ArrayList as example, but
// that's language and context dependent. Use arrays if the size
// won't change.
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> cities;
```

Filling the datastructure becomes quite easy, just run over the list and add:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < cities.get(i).size(); j++) {
        String city = cities.get(i).get(j));
        if(!lookupMap.containsKey(city) {
            lookupMap.put(city, new ArrayList<IndexTuple>());
        }
        lookupMap.get(city).add(new IndexTuple(i, j));
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Note that, if you do not have to iterate over the original list, you can just remove it after building the hashing map or tree. As the indices are remembered, you can still find out the sequences the city belongs to. It will be a kind of mess to reconstruct the lists for iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually not change the data structure. A list of lists is a pretty nice data structure for 2 reasons:

1. You can use indices like Mainlist(5)(7) and basically treat you list as a big 2D array (with different column sizes).
2. Easy to "imagine" in your head so that further coding will be easier

So depending on your programming language either do a double for loop:

```
for all elements in mainlist:
   for all elements in sublist:
       if element == target:
           break;
       endif
    endfor
endfor
```

Or even better you could use the foreach loops:

- C++ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arich/archive/2004/09/08/227139.aspx
- Java http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=196

In any case, foreach is very efficient and will iterate all your lists and stop (once you say break;). All other transformations could cost you a lot of computation.

Another option is as izaera said using hashmaps but the rest of your code (if you wish to manipulate the lists) is going to be a bit more difficult, so keep it simple. :)

Comment: The break alone isn't enough, it breaks only one loop. Furthermore, I don't think this will be efficient enough. The way the question was asked, it sounded like fast lookup was real important, even if it required some preprocessing.

Comment: @Noctua: true, even if there was some processing in building the structure its fine but search should be quick. Main reason for this is that the search required to be done very often ~ 2000 searches each time

Comment: @Noctua: You are right there is one more break missing (either by saying specifically which loop to break or with a variable assignment and one more if in the main loop and then a break. But I think he gets the main picture ! :P

Comment: For the speed thing, usually a CPU, any decent CPU is fast enough to process 5000 * 100 loops but if that is still not fast enough then hashmaps are the way to go since they don't iterate over the whole content but use hash code to faster access the right fields.